# Power suppply sounds like a hard drive being defragmented

Tags: power-supply, noise

Came back from a holiday and noticed that my computer makes a new sound: the sound of a (quiet) hard drive being defragmented, i.e. reading/writing lots of data. Was worried it was one of my hard drives but turns out to be the PSU. The sound intensifies under CPU load. The PSU is only a year and a half old. Model is "Nexus NX-5000 R3 530W Real Silent 80+".

My first and immediate question is if I should stop using the computer. Is it possible that the PSU will send a surge or similar and fry the other components?

Second question: what could it be?

Comment: Could be a fan bearing

Comment: Mechanical hardware that makes sounds is a sign of future failure and should be replaced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PSU is usually silent, like a laptop or other power brick. The fan(s) are what makes noise. Unless something is REALLY wrong, then there'd probably be a sizzling type sound & smoke too.

Extra noise could be the fan starting to fail. You could try testing if it's the fan by taking something firm (like a q-tip maybe) and slowing down the fan for a second, or ***very very briefly*** stopping the fan & see if the sound changes...

If it's still under warranty, I'd look into a warranty repair, especially if it's easy like a local store you can walk it into.

Replacing the fan yourself is an option, it's just a regular fan with probably 2 (maybe 3) wires to cut & solder in a new one. BUT there are some **dangerous** things (capacitors) inside a PSU to be careful of, and that would void the warranty.

Or if the fan still "blows" good you could just leave it, might keep blowing and get louder until it quits but it could take months... or could take a day.

If the PSU fan gets too slow or quits, the PSU would overheat and it could just shut off (one I had did that, computer would just shutdown, I think the fan was too slow but don't know why), or the PSU could send damaging voltages?

Extra idea (good/bad?): there's also a guy on youtube who adds a tiny bit of light oil, like sewing machine oil, under the sticker of his fans to lube them, if there's a metal bit you can see that spins with the blades. He thinks it'll make them last longer & be quieter. I'd be a little worried about spraying oil all over the place, and a new cheap little fan is only $5 or $10... but it's another DIY option

Comment: I see. Thanks. Just out of curiosity, can a fan make a sound that is similar to the sound of a hard drive reading/writing constantly? Also, is there a explanation to why the sounds is correlated to CPU load? The ticking/rattling gets more intense when scrolling through a PDF document for example.

Comment: Bad fans I've heard sound kind of rattling, little like rocks rattling around, usually repetitive but sometimes random. There's some videos on youtube for "computer fan bad bearing" but it's hard to hear with most people's camera mic's and the wind noise. [This one's not the worst video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wuSGDNg7Eog)

Comment: I think recent power supplies adjust their fans according to their temperature, higher temp = faster fan = noisier fan. And they get hotter if your computer is using more power = high CPU usage, or video card, hard drive, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Mechanical grinding noise is probably a bearing going bad slowly.

You best bet may be to replace the fan if possible.

Here's a related thread on psu fan replacements : http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=258799

Comment: In the meantime, do you think it is safe to ignore the sound and use the computer?

Comment: My best guess would be a bad fan bearing... These can die slow deaths.  Once they die, your heat will increase since you'll lose cooling power... But probably not a danger of a damaging power surge.  See if you can isolate the noise to a particular fan. Sometimes the noise will disappear with a little pressure on the central hub.

Comment: I've used many, many computers with fans going bad ... Typically case fans or video card fans. It's annoying until it dies... The noise is my cue to 1. Order a replacement and 2. Watch and listen carefully.

Comment: No; it's not safe to ignore mechanical devices should not make unusual sounds

Comment: Good news is that it seems like the warranty is still valid! I will have to contact the seller. I need however to use my computer this week and can therefore not send any parts off... Will have to cross my fingers and use it despite the (low) noise.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the fan. It's called "coil whine", and I know exactly what you mean. Literally sounds like a hard drive that's reading/writing. It's usually indicative of a failing PSU. You're not crazy!